# Segmentation fault and pointer to non existing struct is not null

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct treeNode *tree;
typedef struct treeNode {
  int key; 
  tree left, right;
} treeNode;
```

with this tree:

[image: my tree]

problem:
mytree->left->left->left is NOT NULL. But why?! How Can I check if I reached the end of a branch?

```
  tree mytree = (tree)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
  mytree->key = 17;
  mytree->left = (tree)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
  mytree->left->key = 5;
  mytree->left->left = (tree)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
  mytree->left->right = (tree)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
  mytree->left->left->key = 20;
  mytree->left->right->key = 2;
  mytree->right = (tree)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
  mytree->right->key = 1;
  mytree->right->left = (tree)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
  mytree->right->right = (tree)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
  mytree->right->left->key = 6;
  mytree->right->right->key = 3;
```

Comment: Did you set it to `NULL`? No? So why would it be?

Comment: Did you set the left and right child to `NULL` when you initialize every node?

Comment: Without seeing the code you used to create the tree, it's not possible for us to help you. Can you please post the code you used?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: Don't you have your answer already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you allocate a treeNode, do you initialize the pointers to NULL?  C doesn't magically initialize dynamically allocated memory.

You added your initialization code.  `malloc()` does not initialize the contents of the memory to zero.  There's nothing in your code that would set the `left` and `right` pointers to `NULL`.  That's why they aren't `NULL`.  You can either initialize them by hand (best for you), or use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.  `calloc()` initializes the allocated memory to zero.